# How to use standart hydrators in laravel/Doctrine

Tags: php, laravel, orm, doctrine

I just cant find the information how to do that in laravel/doctrine

```
$q->fetchOne(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

there are info how to add custom hydrators, but how to just use standart one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround that i found is that laravel\doctrine is just adapter and also it depends on standard doctrine library, and all doctrine functionality can be used as well. I'm not sure if it is right way, but it is possible just import hydrators directly from doctrine.